# Xamarin.Forms ListView with 2 different select options

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView, where when you click on the item, it opens a new page with lots of details, however, if you click on the Name (title) it should show a popup with details of that customer.

My problem is that the Name/Title click is not working.

```js
public ICommand CommandShowInfo { get; set; }

public CustomerListViewModel(INavigation navigation, DateTime month)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
        CommandShowInfo = new Command(ShowCustomerInfo);
        ....
    }


private async void ShowCustomerInfo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj.ToString() == "SHOW-MAIN")
            {
                CustInfoSelectedCustomer = MainCustomer;

                showDetails = true;
            }
            else if (obj.ToString() == "SHOW")
            {
                // TODO get correct customer to populate popup
                CustInfoSelectedCustomer = SelectedCustomer;

                showDetails = true;
            }
            else
            {
                showDetails = false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SummaryReports.ResultSet}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.View>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,5,0,5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Spacing="0">
       <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,0,0,5">
         <Label
                                        Text="{Binding Customer.Name}"
                                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        Font="{x:Static statics:Fonts.ListItemTitle}"
                                        TextColor="{x:Static statics:Palette.ListItemTitle}" />

                                                 <Image Source="info.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="20">
                                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                            Command="{Binding CommandShowInfo}"
                                                            CommandParameter="SHOW" />
                                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Image>

                                </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout>
       <StackLayout>
        ....
```

Comment: where is CommandShowInfo defined?

Comment: Check if the constructor CustomerListViewModel above is called.

Comment: The constructor is called when creating the screen, and outside of the Listview, the CommandShowInfo is working correctly, its just that inside the ListView it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already run your code,there is no problem.You can try this

```
<Label 
        Text="{Binding Name}" 
        Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}">
   <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
              Command="{Binding CommandShowInfo}"
              CommandParameter="Binding ." />
         </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

And in modle ,you should be sure that `CommandShowInfo` must be in **ListView.ItemSource** ,esle there will not work.Like this

```
 class Monkey
{
   public string Name { set; get; }
   public System.Windows.Input.ICommand CommandShowInfo { get; set; }
}

 class MonkeysViewModel
{
    public MonkeysViewModel()
    {

         private async void ShowCustomerInfo(object obj)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("true");
         }
        Monkeys = new List<Monkey>();
        //f = new F[5];
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey
        {
            Name = "AS",
            CommandShowInfo = new Command(ShowCustomerInfo)
         });
     }
 }
```

In contentapge

```
 BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel();
```

In xaml

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
```

So the `CommandShowInfo` can work.

Comment: Hmm.. are you saying that my Model "SummaryReports.ResultSet" should have the CommandShowInfo functionality in it, rather than the ViewModel?